# Observable wait for a function with multiple observable to finish

Tags: angular, typescript, service, rxjs, observable

I have two services config, auth which have a code similar to this :

```
public init = (): Observable<AppConfig> => {
    return this._http.post(this.actionUrl, JSON.stringify(this.APP_CONFIG), { headers: this.headers })
      .map((response: Response) => response.json() as AppConfig)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

And these two services are called in one final service which will be called on every components in my Angular 5 application :

```
@Injectable()
export class PageService {

  constructor(private configService: ConfigService, private authService: AuthService) { }

  config: AppConfig;
  auth: Auth;
  grants: Grants;

  init() {
    Observable.forkJoin(
      this.configService.init(),
      this.authService.init(),
      this.authService.grants())
      .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.config = data[0];
        this.auth = data[1];
        this.grants = data[2];

        // Logs
        console.log(this.config);
        console.log(this.auth);
        console.log(this.grants);
      });
  }
}
```

Here is how I call it in my component :

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  columns: any[];

  constructor(private pageService: PageService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.pageService.init();
    this.userAccessPanel();
  }

  userAccessPanel = () => {
    console.log('Grant : ', this.pageService.grants);
  }
}
```

The problem is that `this.pageService.grants` shows undefined I guess because it's called before I could get the data from the server. But in that case I couldn't find any way on the internet to solve my problem.

How can I do to launch `this.userAccessPanel()` after being sure `this.pageService.init()` finished and got all the data from the server ?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

init() has to return an observable

```
init() {
return Observable.forkJoin(
  this.configService.init(),
  this.authService.init(),
  this.authService.grants())
  .map(([config,auth,grants])=>{config,auth,grants})
 }
```

then in your other component

```
ngOnInit() {
this.pageService.init()
.map(obj=>this.userAccessPanel(obj.grants)).subscribe()
 }

 userAccessPanel = (grants) => {
console.log('Grant : ', grants);
 }
```

Comment: `.map(([config,auth,grants])=>{config,auth,grants})` should be `.map(([config,auth,grants])=>[config,auth,grants])`
Works great thanks